# real analysis - pointwise & uniform convergence of certain sequence of function - how to complete lacks in reasoning?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I solved the following question:

> Investigate the pointwise convergence and uniform convergence of the following sequence of function $\{f_n\}$ on the interval $[0,1]$, where 
>   $$
> f_n(x)=
> \begin{cases}
>  nx^2, &x\in[0, \frac{1}{n}] \\
>  2n - n^2x, &x\in(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n})\\
>  0, &x\in[\frac{2}{n}, 1].
> \end{cases}
> $$

The *solution* is:

Regarding pointwise convergence : $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} f_n(x) = 0$$

Concerning uniform convergence, by checking that: 
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = n \to +\infty \neq 0$$
implies that sequence of function $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise convergent, but not uniform convergent on $[0,1]$.

The problem is that my instructor told me that I should expand algebraically my reasoning on deriving both results stated above (I concluded the above results by analysing behaviour of graph of $f_n(x)$ at the aforementioned interval.

Help very, very, very appreciated as I completely do not know how to formalize my reasoning, whose results are correct. For help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the point wise convergence, just fix $x \in (0,1]$ and remark that $f_n(x)=0$ for every $n$ sufficiently large. Since $f_n(0)=0$, you can immediately conclude.

Can you locate the point where $\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |f_n(x)|$ is attained?

Comment: From the graph of f_n(x), local (and also global) maximum corresponds to argument x = 1/n, where f_n(1/n) = n.

Comment: @Mit You should try to prove rigorously that the maximum is attained at $1/n$.

Comment: Rigorously, by computing 1st derivative of f_n(x) (n fixed) with respect to x and comparing values of extreme points at given 3 intervals,  the maximum (local and global) is attained at 1/n. Is it sufficiently (obviously also including calculations) rigorous now?

Comment: I think so! You just computed the sup-norm and proved that it does not tend to zero.

Comment: Just 1 more point to ask: concerning pointwise convergence, to avoid intuitive phrase "for every n sufficiently large", computation of limit of f_n(x) (fixed x) as n tends to plus infinity in 3 cases giving in each case 0 is sufficiently rigorous reasoning then?